# Using "in" operator compare/convert a string to an int

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-in-loop

I need to find if an integer is found in a list of strings.

context = ['4', '6', '78']

```
if category.id in context:
```

The code above is not working because I compare int(category id) with strings.

I can't use int(context) because context is a list and will give an error.

I can convert category.id to string, but can bad situations appear ?

Using `in` operator it is possible to convert the strings to int, or I need to use a `for loop` ?

Comment: ...did you try str(category.id) in context?

Comment: @jkm `I can convert category.id to string, but can bad situations appear ?` seems like OP did thought of that but doesn't know if it's the correct route?

Comment: Are you considering this two entries '01' and '001' as same or different?

Comment: Either `str(category.id) in context` or `category.id in map(int, context)`

Comment: To follow up on user1190882, if you consider those as different, converting it to string is fine, if you consider those are the same, convert them into int, and make `context` hold `int` types instead of string types.

Comment: @MooningRawr Yeah, my bad, sorry. Bad situations can always appear.  But in this case, unlikely.

Comment: @jkm I thought about that, but I'm not 100% sure, if the conversion is correct for all type of numbers(very big numbers)

Comment: To solve this correctly you _need_ to find out if  '01' and '001' are considered to be the same ID or different. Until you clarify that, there's no point continuing.

Comment: Alternatively, the question is "can any members of `context` have leading zeroes?"

Comment: At any rate, the _ideal_ solution is to make `context` a set of integers, rather than a list of strings. (But that of course has other implications.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also consider using a list comprehension to convert `context` to a list of integers.

```
context_ints = [int(i) for i in context]
if category.id in context_ints:
    ... do stuff ...
```

If `context` is guaranteed to be a list of strings that can sensibly be converted to integers, this may be the safest route for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just update the id to a string, like this:

```
class cat():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

category = cat(4)

context = ['4', '6', '78']

if str(category.id) in context:
    print('True')

#output
True
```